# Installing modules into a custom site-packages directory

Tags: python, django, easy-install

I have inherited a half-finished django project
which uses a custom `site-packages` directory that
is checked into subversion along with the code.

Being a newbie to python, I'm wondering if I can just
copy the contents of some eggs - that I want to add
into the django project - directly into this
`site-packages` directory from my ubuntu `dist-packages` directory.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

Are there gotchas that I should watch out for if I do this manually ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

> virtualenv is a tool to create
>   isolated Python environments.